# How to POST with redirect in PHP

Tags: php, magento, redirect, microservices, http-redirect

Detail flow

[image]

Description

1. magento site send post to API
2. API middleware/microservices save order into db and redirected to payment gateway
3. payment gateway response redirect to API payment
4. redirect callback to magento

magento code. send post to api

```
$uri = sprintf('%s/%s', 'http://api.tld', '/request');
$config = array(
    'adapter'   => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
    'curloptions' => array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true),
);
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri, $config);
$client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
$client->setRawData(json_encode(['api' => $api, 'pg' => $data]));
$response = $client->request();
```

code api middleware and must redirect to payment gateway

```
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($content, true);
$pg = $data['payment_gateway'];// require post to payment gateway

$payment = 'http://paymentgateway.tld/purchase';
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => $payment, 'allow_redirects' => true]);
$res = $client->request('POST', null, $pg);

// the problem is not redirect to $payment.
header("Location: $payment");
```

the question is how to redirect to payment gateway in API middleware after sending post from magento site

Comment: It really depends on the Payment gateway

Comment: Payment gateway its ok, no problem. just couldn't redirected to page payment gateway. return blank page